# Ruby on Rails - Starting server as a live website. [Linode]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have made an account on Linode website and have a "linode" running. I have a server running using ruby on rails. The command I used is the following:

`rails server --binding=<ip_adress>`

The server starts up without issue. The question I have is why can't I visit the the side I created using my browser, just by putting the ip_address in the browser? The server logs display the following

`Environment: development Listening on tcp:<ip_address>:3000`

I can visit this ip_address on my browser but I need to add the ":3000" in the browser so I can view the site.

Shouldn't I be able to just visit the stand alone ip_address without entering ":3000"? I also wanted to say I am just learning ruby on rails as well.

I haven't tried anything more than described above

Answer (score 0):

An IP address is a way to identify a machine on the internet.A port is a number assigned to uniquely identify a connection endpoint and to direct data to a specific service.

Therefore, your rails service is a combination of an IP address and a Port number. Since you can have different services running on the same machine at the same IP address.

`HTTP` has a default port of 80 which is what your browser will try to access when you don't provide a port.

Most likely, you will want a Reverse Proxy hosted at port 80 that forwards traffic to your rails app.

This post provides a better answer of how this works. https://superuser.com/questions/394078/how-can-i-map-a-domain-name-to-an-ip-address-and-port

##### Not Recommended

If you don't want to use a reverse proxy, you can host the rails server at port 80 itself.
`rails server -p 80`
Note that this requires you to have root permissions on the machine.